# Clear() method clears other variable also

Tags: c#

This is my code excerpt

```
List<int> Ids = new List<int>();
var transModelIds = db.TableName.ToList();
var statModelIds = db.TableName1.ToList();
foreach (var user in metaData){

    foreach(var s in someData){
    Ids.Clear();
    Ids = s.Type.Equals(<Condition>) ? transModelIds : statModelIds;
...
    }
}
```

what happening is after the first iteration of **someData** loop,

when Ids.Clear() is executed , Ids, transModelIds, statModelIds all will be cleared

**Why?**

But it will work if i put Ids.Clear() above the for loop:

```
Ids.Clear();
foreach(var s in someData){<...Code...>}
```

The code works fine

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. We don't have enough information to help you at the moment.

Comment: Please note that [tag:model-view-controller] is intended for questions concerning the *pattern*; if your question deals with the ASP.NET implementation, use the [tag:asp.net-mvc] tag.

Comment: @TiesonT. Not that this question has anything remotely to do with any kind of MVC, pattern or not. The tag removal is entirely appropriate. =D

Comment: @J.Steen T'was more of a "for future reference" comment, in case the OP wanted to know why I removed the tag, and/or if they add content later that makes it relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that a List<T> is a reference type. If you code:

```
Ids = s.Type.Equals(<Condition>) ? transModelIds : statModelIds;
```

you do not copy the list but make the reference `Ids` point to the same list(s).

To solve it:

```
List<int> Ids = new List<int>();
var transModelIds = db.TableName.ToList();
var statModelIds = db.TableName1.ToList();
foreach (var user in metaData){

    foreach(var s in someData){
        Ids.Clear();
        Ids.AddRange(s.Type.Equals(<Condition>) ? transModelIds : statModelIds);
        /*... don't set the reference to the list but add the items from the source to your destination */
    }
}
```

Alternative you can create a new list in the inner loop too if you need it only in this scope (as Jon's comment allready suggested we can't help without the full working code):

```
var transModelIds = db.TableName.ToList();
var statModelIds = db.TableName1.ToList();
foreach (var user in metaData){

    foreach(var s in someData){
        List<int> ids = new List<int>();
        ids.AddRange(s.Type.Equals(<Condition>) ? transModelIds : statModelIds);
        /*... don't set the reference to the list but add the items from the source to your destination */
    }
}
```

Yet another question you could ask yourself is:

> Do I need the temporary list at all?

In this case just set the reference to the list like you did but don't clear it.

**Edit**

Outer Scope:

```
var transModelIds = db.TableName.ToList();
var statModelIds = db.TableName1.ToList();
List<int> ids = null;
foreach (var user in metaData){

    foreach(var s in someData){
        ids = s.Type.Equals(<Condition>) ? transModelIds : statModelIds;
        /*... additional code but don't modify the lists (clear or remove single items, etc...) ...*/
    }
}
```

Inner Scope:

```
var transModelIds = db.TableName.ToList();
var statModelIds = db.TableName1.ToList();
foreach (var user in metaData){

    foreach(var s in someData){
        List<int> ids = s.Type.Equals(<Condition>) ? transModelIds : statModelIds;
        /*... additional code but don't modify the lists (clear or remove single items, etc...) ...*/
    }
}
```

Comment: @Biswajeet a lot. the implementation depends on the need to have a copy of the list (additional memory is needed) or just a reference to either of the both lists... I'll add the case where you don't copy the lists to the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much,
as we have to assign multiple times, the addrange will sometimes creates duplicate(It's needed), so we retained that Ids.clear, and then added the addRange.

Comment: @Biswajeet any questions left?

Answer (score 3):

Let's have a look what will happen in the case this loop `foreach(var s in someData)` will be executed more that one time.

At the first iteration you're clearing `Ids` and then you're assigning (based on some condition) `Ids = transModelIds` or `Ids = statModelIds`.

Since `List<T>` is **reference** type - in this case you're **not copying**  these lists content back to `Ids` as you may expect, but you're **creating another reference** pointing to `transModelIds` or `statModelIds`.

And in the next iteration of the loop you again clearing `Ids`, but since now it is reference to `transModelIds` or `statModelIds` - you're just clearing these lists.

Answer (score 2):

You are assinging transModelIds and statModelIds to the Ids List. Once you clear the Ids list, you are also clearing all the list assigned to it. Look at the code below:

```
        List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
        List<int> list2 = new List<int>();

        list1.Add(1);
        list1.Add(2);
        list1.Add(3);
        list1.Add(4);
        list1.Add(5);

        list2 = list1;

        list2.Clear();

        Console.WriteLine(list1.Count + "  " + list2.Count);

        Console.ReadLine();
```

It will display "0   0" as you are clearing both lists.

Comment: Gullie this helped me to understand this reference issues, thank you

Comment: The solution to copy the data of two list would be to iterate through all the elements of the source list and add them to the second list. Item by item.

Comment: yeah by using Add() or AddRange() method, got it